# Where do Flatpak packages store their configuration files?

Tags: fedora, configuration, path, flatpak

I use Flatpak to install some applications on my machines for different reasons, now I want to copy my configurations (my home folder hidden directories and files) to a new disk to install Linux on another machine.

PROBLEM IS: I don't now where my Flatpak apps config files are, and I couldn't find them anywhere in my home folder.

note: I use Fedora GNU/Linux on a x86_64 machine, I also use packages from Flathub as well as packages from Fedora repositories.

Can anyone point me to where those config files are, and how to change their path to my home folder?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 26):

The applications store the user data in `~/.var/app`. The configuration for the flatpak itself is located in `~/.local/share/flatpak` (system wide configuration is in `/var/lib/flatpak`).

Answer (score 3):

As @vojtech-trefny mentioned, you can find them in `$HOME/.var/app` (and the other folders he mentioned). If you'd like a GUI to make life easier for you, though, I'd recommend [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) for you: there you can have a nice overview over each installed flatpak package and you can easily change any setting you'd like.

Comment: Flatseal is nice, but there's a bootstrapping problem, you can't use flatseal to view/change the configuration of flatseal before starting it - I wanted to know for sure what flatseal would have access to (it would be better if it was distributed as a package for my distribution instead of only as a flatpak). So I highly recommend knowing the paths.

Comment: Flatseal is a replacement only for the second half of Vojtech's answer - i.e. configuration of Flatpak sandbox of that app. The app-specific file for configuration (e.g. autostart with OS, close to tray area, autosave frequency, etc.) is not displayed (or known) to Flatseal.